# Enforce TypeScript union type type-checking for object literals

Tags: typescript, object-literal, union-types

For the following code, `invalidUnion` is not marked as an error but only `validUnion.b` is:

```js
export type A = { a: string; }
export type B = { b: string; }

const validUnion: A | B = {
  a: ''
}

validUnion.b = ''; // Error

const invalidUnion: A | B = {
  a: '',
  b: ''
} // No error
```

When a discriminant is added, this works fine. (See the fuller example in [the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTC04yunb+4CgQAIDqBLALgCwPYCuWKAJhgM4DGAThgLYYB2Aho1gFwpMBuzANhhIBVRhjyMu5FIzzFqAU0p4A5qPLySKZlJ79ByMAiPGTxxInkAPAA55qxLAE9r8lAEEUAXhQBvLZ3IsWkZlAG4UAF8LGzsHZ1cAIS9fFAAjAKCmMMjzJUZAlF4BEgBJNnlqdUosMUZODwAyFCTvH0QUfxQAci6AGna0zh7EKMQ8gt1isqwKqprxepQmlt8B5iGukdzxAqLBEVrFgB9m5LaO9e7N0fHiSf3RBfcUE5Xzzp7+jvSrrYNTAGAgEGdDYfBEUgUGj0JisDhcRh7YSPCQlADKKAUSlUFA0Wh0iL0JH+QNJZOg5istnsKCcLncACYzp1AsFsiROABGcJRKmxWnxZpM1qDFCsrLhDkobk5MY7YhIg7iBn1JmvYWrC4bL6kLl-W4IxUolWMl5Cs5rbUDH6fAZSzlbIA).) But is there any way to enforce this kind of type checking even for the `invalidUnion` object literal above?